# Django - (1366, "Incorrect string value:... error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am getting the following error when I try to add a new record via `django` admin:

> OperationalError at /admin/competition/sport/add/
> (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x9F\xC3\xBC' for column 'object_repr' at row 1")
> Request Method: POST
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/competition/sport/add/
> Django Version: 1.11.4
> Exception Type: OperationalError
> Exception Value:
> (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x9F\xC3\xBC' for column 'object_repr' at row 1")

Here is the model:

```
class Sport(models.Model):
    is_team = models.BooleanField(_("Is Team"))
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=200)
```

And options for `mysql` backend at my `settings.py`:

```
'OPTIONS': {
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        'init_command': 'SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;'
                        'SET collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;'
                        "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';"
                        "SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;"
    },
```

I have updated all of the tables and columns to use `utf8mb4` as described [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets)

Nothing has worked so far. I get no error when I try to insert a record that contains unicode characters using `mysql` shell, but the `django` admin gives the error above.

Interestingly the code below works perfectly when i try to insert a record manually:

```
Sport(is_team=True, name="ÜĞüiğÇÖ").save()
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the project runs on django1.11, python3.6 and mysql 5.7.18

Comment: please do not use utf8, use utf8mb4 instead

Comment: I used similar method suggested above and it works. 
```ALTER TABLE django_admin_log CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE <ALL_OTHER_TABLES_I_HAVE> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;```

Answer (score 6):

You have to modify the django_admin_log character set

```
ALTER TABLE django_admin_log CHANGE object_repr object_repr VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
           self.name = str(self.name.encode('unicode_escape'))
```

you need to encode with unicode_escape before saving as mention in above example (self.name = str(self.name.encode('unicode_escape'))), no need to do any other setting or db changes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling on DB level i build my custom Field to handle encoding and decoding of data.

```
class BaseEmojiField:
    def to_python(self, value ):
        if isinstance(value, str) or value is None:
            if value is None:
                return value
            else:
                encoded_string = str(value).encode('unicode_escape')
                return encoded_string
        return str(value)
    
    def from_db_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if str(value).startswith("b'"):
            value = bytes(str(value).replace("b'","")[0:-1].replace('\\\\','\\'), 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
        elif str(value).isascii():
            value = bytes(str(value), 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
            return value
        return value
```

Then you can use it with both Charfield and TextField

```
class CustomEmojiCharField(BaseEmojiField , models.CharField):
    pass

class CustomEmojiTextField(BaseEmojiField ,models.TextField):
    pass
```

so where you need emoji use these fields instead of models.CharField and models.TextField
Also there is one drawback that if you edit anything from django admin site it goes int django admin log. admin log uses str method to retreive information of your instance. so in **str** method dont use field with emoji/special character.

Answer (score -1):

I had RichTextUploadingField for a field and when I put emojies inside the field, it returns the error you have. I just removed the emojies and it works fine!