# Django unicode conversion stuck when saving in admin log?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

**1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBC\x88Pac...' for column 'object_repr' at row 1"**
[image: 1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBC\x88Pac...' for column 'object_repr' at row 1"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - (1366, "Incorrect string value:... error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665455/django-1366-incorrect-string-value-error)

Answer (score 1):

For this you just have to run query in your sql table to make it Utf-8  encoded.Because encoding get stuck only when the string encoding does not match the encoding of column of table.

```
ALTER TABLE django_admin_log CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```